# Access to redux state during Selenium testing

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, react-redux

Recipee sharing here,

For my app, wanted to automate user PoV testing with Selenium and told myself that being able to read the state and send redux actions through Selenium would be great.

Selenium is driven from NodeJs.

In node JS to send a Redux action to the app:

```
const state = await driver
      .executeAsyncScript(
        "window.stCap({action: arguments[0], cb: arguments[arguments.length - 1]});",
        { type: "global_ST_CAP_GET" }
      )
```

- Arg0 is a redux action (here named "global_ST_CAP_GET")
- Arg1 is added automatically by driver.executeAsyncScript, it is the callback function

In one of the helpers file:

```
let globalActionRequest;

export const globalActionRequestSet = ar => {
  globalActionRequest = ar;
};

window.stCap = function({ action, cb }) {
    globalActionRequest({
    ...action,
    cb
  });
};
```

- stCap calls the function set into `globalActionRequest` that will send the event to redux middleware

In one of the top react component initialization (to be able to "enter" the redux world...), put into `globalActionRequest` the function provided by `mapDispatchToProps`

```
import { globalActionRequestSet } from "...appropriate file..."

class ... extends React.component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        globalActionRequestSet(props.actionRequest)
    }
    ...
}

mapDispatchToProps = {
    actionRequest: action => action
}
```

- Here, the code driving Selenium is able to send any redux action to your app.

And at the end, in the "sagas" file, make a action to send back the state (to be used later in the code driving selenium)

```
const global_ST_CAP_GET = function* ({cb}) {
    const state = yield sagas.select(state => state);
    cb(state);
}

// to add into root sagas
fork(function*() {
    yield takeEvery("global_ST_CAP_GET", global_ST_CAP_GET);
})
```

With this trick, is is possible with one tool (selenium) to test the outer of an app but also the inner (by sending actions and read redux state).

Hope you'll like it, happy to hear about any suggestion